# кодирование Хаффмана

Tags: java, huffman

По данной непустой строке `s` длины не более `10^4`, состоящей из строчных букв латинского алфавита, постройте оптимальный беспрефиксный код. В первой строке выведите количество различных букв `k`, встречающихся в строке, и размер получившейся закодированной строки. В следующих `k` строках запишите коды букв в формате `letter: code`. В последней строке выведите закодированную строку.

```
Sample Input 1:
a

Sample Output 1:
1 1
a: 0
0

Sample Input 2:
abacabad

Sample Output 2:
4 14
a: 0
b: 10
c: 110
d: 111
01001100100111
```

Я написал код, но программа падает в валидаторе. С ошибкой:

> Failed test #7. wrong output format: list index out of range

Найти ошибку не получилось, если можете - помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код:

[Или ссылка на pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3a19Pc4V)

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by mac on 12.11.15.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        String string = in.nextLine();
        int value;
        String key;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            key = "" + string.charAt(i);
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                value = map.get(key) + 1; // получение значения по ключу те частоту
                map.put(key,value);
            } else {
                map.put(key,1);
            }
        }
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        List<Element> q = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
            q.add(new Element(list.get(i).getValue(), list.get(i).getKey()));
        }

        Comparator comparator = new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Element one = (Element) o1;
                Element two = (Element) o2;
                return one.p-two.p;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(q,comparator);
        int dl = list.size();
        Element buffer1;
        Element buffer2;

        if (list.size() == 1) {
            System.out.println(1 + " " + string.length());
            System.out.println(string.charAt(0) + ": " + "0");
            String simplecode = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                simplecode += "0";
            }
            System.out.println(simplecode);
        } else {

            do {
                buffer1 = extractMin(q);
                buffer2 = extractMin(q);
                // добавляем элемент с именем сум двух мин элементов и приоритетом сум двух мин элементов
                insertElement(q, new Element(buffer1.p + buffer2.p, buffer1.v + buffer2.v, buffer1, buffer2));
            } while (q.size() > 1);

            // получаем код 'a'


            Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

            String[] halfresult = new String[q.get(0).v.length()];


            for (int i = 0; i < q.get(0).v.length(); i++) {
                String code = "";
                String symbol = "" + q.get(0).v.charAt(i);
                Element buffCoding = q.get(0);
                while ((buffCoding.leftchild != null) && (buffCoding.rightchild != null)) {
                    if (buffCoding.leftchild.v.contains(symbol)) {
                        code += "0";
                        buffCoding = buffCoding.leftchild;
                    } else if (buffCoding.rightchild.v.contains(symbol)) {
                        code += "1";
                        buffCoding = buffCoding.rightchild;
                    }
                }
                dictionary.put(symbol, code);
                halfresult[i] = (symbol + ": " + code);
            }

            String resultCode = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                key = "" + string.charAt(i);
                resultCode += dictionary.get(key);
            }

            System.out.println(list.size() + " " + resultCode.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < halfresult.length; i ++) {
                System.out.println(halfresult[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(resultCode);
        }
    }


    public static class Element{
        int p;
        String v;
        Element leftchild = null;
        Element rightchild = null;
        public Element(int p, String v) {
            this.p = p;
            this.v = v;
        }

        public Element(int p, String v, Element leftchild, Element rightchild) {
            this.p = p;
            this.v = v;
            this.leftchild = leftchild;
            this.rightchild = rightchild;
        }

    }

    public static Element extractMin(List<Element> q) {
        Element buffer = q.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < q.size(); i++) {
            q.set(i-1,q.get(i));
        }
        q.remove(q.size()-1);
        return buffer;
    }

    public static void insertElement(List<Element> q, Element el) {
        if (q.size() == 0) {
            q.add(el);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = q.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (el.p >= q.get(i).p) {
                q.add(i+1,el);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Используйте отладчик.

Comment: использовал, дело в том, что я не знаю, что за тест в котором ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Подошел к вопросу прямо, сделал перебор всех возможных строк. Для строки `cbaaa` выполняется условие `q.get(0).v.length() != list.size()`, т.е. длина вашего массива `halfresults` в который вы скидываете пары "символ: код" не совпадает с длиной `list`, из которого вы выводите количество символов.

Ваша программа выдает:

```
3 8
a: 
nullnull
```

https://ideone.com/vXkdr7

Comment: огромное спасибо вам, буду копать. Вы сделали цикл и в нём перебирали?

Comment: да, вынес все, кроме ввода строки из main в отдельный метод, принимающий строку, и подставлял в него значения.

Comment: могли бы кинуть код вашего перебора?